# In the Kalevala, what is Väinämöinen?

Tags: character-analysis, finnish-language, the-kalevala

The character of [Väinämöinen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A4in%C3%A4m%C3%B6inen) is central to the Finnish epic [the Kalevala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalevala). But from reading about him and the stories online, I can't figure out whether he was a god or a mortal man. Some of the myths claim that he played a role in the creation of the world (but as the first man rather than as a god?) Later on he seems to have a more human role, e.g. seeking a bride for himself. It seems that he must have lived for a very long time, but is he immortal or simply long-lived?

**What is Väinämöinen: a god, an immortal, a hero, a human, ... ?**

Answer (score -1):

Väinämöinen is the immortal wizard of magic and poetry.

> [WAINAMOINEN](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/kveng/kvrune03.htm), ancient minstrel,
>   Passed his years in full contentment,
>   On the meadows of Wainola,
>   On the plains of Kalevala,
>   Singing ever wondrous legends,
>   Songs of ancient wit and wisdom,
>   Chanting one day, then a second,
>   Singing in the dusk of evening,
>   Singing till the dawn of morning,

Comment: The verse you've quoted says that he's an "ancient minstrel", but it doesn't say he's an "immortal wizard of magic and poetry". Please can you [edit] to justify your conclusion better and address the things mentioned in the question?

Comment: Well on Finnish verse he is called a 'Tietäjä' 
`Vaka vanha Väinämöinen, tietäjä iän-ikuinen,`
Which can translated as wizard. and his spells are in form on poems.
So you can call can him a wizard.